# List<T> defined as member of class

Tags: c#

I have a list where i want the type to be definined by the call for example in the class i want something like

```
public class ClassName
{
    public ListType<T> ListName { get; set; }
    // other class items
}
```

and then the usage to be what sets the class type like

```
var className = new ClassName()
{
    ListType<int> = data
};
```

so basically thats what i want, i have it working using dynamic so the class is

```
public class ClassName
{
    public ListType<dynamic> ListName { get; set; }
    // other class items
}
```

and the call is

```
var className = new ClassName()
{
    ListType<dynamic> = data
};
```

this works but i would like to know if there is a better way to do this so i dont have to use dynamic

oh almost forgot to mention the ListType is

```
public class ListType<T> : List<T>
{
}
```

and so doesnt fail by having different types passed to it

thanks

edit: 
realised my usage of the code on stack overflow differed from my code

the ListType has a constructor that takes 3 arguments so the usage is more

```
var className = new ClassName()
{
    ListName = new ListType<Type>(x, y, z)
}
```

Comment: "`new ClassName() { ListType<dynamic> = data; }`". Does this really work? I've never seen such syntax.

Comment: Well in my code yes, im not working with ints tho its working with a model from data entity so in my actual code its more new ClassName() {ListType<dynamic> = (Db.GetAll()) }; which gets all of the records from of the model type (made a mistake in typing into stack overflow too, shouldnt be a semicolon after data)

Comment: that syntax is used with the {get;set;} it allows you to create a new object and set the values without having a constructor, its one of the things that seems to be used a lot with MVC + viewModels if your interested in finding more examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
public class ClassName<T>
{
    public ListType<T> ListName { get; set; }
    // other class items
}
```

then use it like this:

```
var className = new ClassName<int>()
{
    ListName = data;
};
```

Comment: i did try this however when i did that i ended up having to specify the type twice or i got compiler errors, so the usage was more like var className = new ClassName<int>() { ListName<int> = data };

Comment: have edited the original post so the usage matches my actual program mode so it was more like var className = new ClassName<ModelName>() { ListName = new ListItem<ModelName>(x, y, z) }; while this approach works i again dont like the repetition of ModelName

Answer (score 1):

Slight addition to Bertrand's answer gives you a way to not repeat the type argument in you specific use case, or even not mention it:

```
public static class ClassName
{
    public static ClassName<T> Create<T>(ListType<T> list)
    {
        return new ClassName<T> { ListName = list };
    }

    public static ClassName<T> Create<T>(params T[] list)
    {
        return new ClassName<T> { ListName = new ListType<T>(list) };
    }
}
```

Using the first method, you can write something like

```
ClassName.Create(new ListType<SomeType>(x, y, z));
```

using the second method, you can even write

```
ClassName.Create(x, y, z);
```

and let the compiler figure out that `T` is `SomeType`, but that doesn't work always.

Note that `ClassName` is different class than `ClassName<T>` and you might want to name it differently, e.g. `ClassNameFactory`.